# Standard lwc lightning/platformShowToastEvent module and force:showToast aura event don't work in Lightning Community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-community, toast

We have community with Registration Page replaced with custom Lightning Community Page. The page is build with Aura component, which is using lwc components.
Trying firing force:showToast from aura and ShowToastEvent from lwc nothing happens, javascript executes succesfully, no errors/warnings in console.

There is an assumption, that nothing can handle these(this) events in community.

But according to documentations it should work:

- "To display a toast notification in Lightning Experience or Lightning communities" - [link to doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_toast);
- "This event is handled by the one.app container. It’s supported in Lightning Experience, Salesforce app, and Lightning communities." - [link to doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:showToast/documentation).

Couldn't find known issues at the moment of writing.
Do I understand documentation correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While documentation is says that ShowToast is available in Lightning Experience, but not in Lightning Communities, it is actually supported in Lightning Communities, except the login page.

There is information here: force:showToast is not available on login pages.
https://www.thecloudfountain.com/salesforce-lightning-forceshowtoast/

Comment: Yes. I was using it on Registration Page, which is a part of "Login" pages